# Javascript alert from JSON response

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, alert

I'm trying to build an app that gets data from server with getJSON and then alerts the row. This is the code I use but it doesn't show the row from JSON, it just says "undefined". What could be the reason for this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("MyURL/test.php",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        alert(field.MESSAGE);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

This is the JSON response:

```
{"key":[{"message":"test"}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` isn't an array. `result.key` is an array.  Also your field's property is `message`, not `MESSAGE`:

```
$.each(result.key, function(i, field){
    alert(field.message);
});
```

Answer (score -2):

accessing objects in json is case sensitive

Comment: Please don't post single-line answers. Explain the issue. -1

Comment: @Manishearth oh... I thought I explain how to access properties in a json object was in "case sensitive" isn't it right? or you want an example how to do that? then here is an example if you access message do it like this "field.message" and not "field.MESSAGE" cause the message property is not in capital letters but rather written in small letters so accessing it with capital letters would not work cause it's case sensitive and would mean another different property from the object. does it make sense? (--,)